Call to undefined method Dompdf\\FrameDecorator\\Page::add_line()
I am trying to send an email with 2 pdf attachments but when in the controller I call getRejectedReport method it return me error says that Call to undefined method Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Page::add_line() while the other method getReport run successfully and generate pdf that goes in email as attachment.
getting this Call to undefined method Dompdf\\FrameDecorator\\Page::add_line()
I have almost same code and same logic for both pdf blade files. here is my sample code ....
class ChecklistController extends AppBaseController
{
    protected $pdf;

    public function __construct(
        ComplaintRepository $compRepository,
        PDf $pdf,
    ) {
        $this->compRepository = $compRepository;
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }

    public function getReport($id, $type = 'stream')
    {
        $view = 'pdf.report';
        $filePath =  app()->basePath() . '/public/uploads/pdf';

        $pdf = $this->pdf->loadView($view, [
            'content' => $data, 
        ])->setPaper('a4');

        $pdf->setWarnings(false)->save($filePath);
    }

    public function getRejectedReport($id, $type = 'stream')
    {
        $view = 'pdf.rejected-report';
        $filePath =  app()->basePath() . '/public/uploads/pdf';

        $pdf = $this->pdf->loadView($view, [
            'content' => $data, 
        ])->setPaper('a4');

        $pdf->setWarnings(false)->save($filePath);
    }

}


This is a common problem that occur when you are using the same $pdf instance for the next pdf generation.
so it is better changing your method with a fresh PDF instance see the following code

Make a new PDF instance like **$pdf = app(PDF::class); **

public function getRejectedReport($id, $type = 'stream')
{
    $view = 'pdf.rejected-report';
    $filePath =  app()->basePath() . '/public/uploads/pdf';

     // Make a fresh instance of pdf here
    $pdf = app(PDF::class)->loadView($view, [
        'content' => $data, 
    ])->setPaper('a4');

    $pdf->setWarnings(false)->save($filePath);
}

